# hibernate annotation curd operation in j2ee

Tags: hibernate

I have seen all your suggestion But no one was helped me please solve my mistake in j2ee curd operation in hibernate annotation..
Please help me to solve my problem in hibernate annotation

this is my pojo class

```
package com.pojo1;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="csl_employee")
public class Student {


    @Id
    @Column(name="ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column(name="fname")
    private String fname;

    @Column(name="lname")
    private String lname;
    @Column(name="add")
    private String add;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getFname() {
        return fname;
    }
    public void setFname(String fname) {
        this.fname = fname;
    }
    public String getLname() {
        return lname;
    }
    public void setLname(String lname) {
        this.lname = lname;
    }
    public String getAdd() {
        return add;
    }
    public void setAdd(String add) {
        this.add = add;
    }


}


this is my Jsp File

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="Studentdemoservlet" method="post">
<table>
<tr>
<td>First Name:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="fname"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Last Name:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="lname"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Address:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="add"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="submit" name="action" value="submit"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>


this is my servlet

package com.pojo1;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Studentdemoservlet
 */
public class Studentdemoservlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Studentdemoservlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String fname=request.getParameter("fname");
        String lname=request.getParameter("lname");
        String add=request.getParameter("add");


        Student student=new Student();

        student.setFname(fname);
        student.setLname(lname);
        student.setAdd(add);

        CreateStudent.intercourse(student);



    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}

this is my Insert method for student in hibernate

package com.pojo1;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

public class CreateStudent {

    public static void intercourse(Student student) {

        SessionFactory sessionFactory;


        sessionFactory=Util.getSessionFactory();

        Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();

        Transaction t=session.beginTransaction();

        session.save(student);

        t.commit();

        session.close();

        sessionFactory.close();



    }

}


this is my Util Class

package com.pojo1;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;

public class Util {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    static
    {
        try
        {
            sessionFactory=new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        }
        catch(Throwable th){
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(th);

        }
    }
    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory(){
        return sessionFactory;

    }

}

this is my configuration file

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>

        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javadb</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
         <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property> 
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
         <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property> 
         <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>   
           <property name="show_sql">true</property> 
      <!--       <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property> 
       <mapping class="com.pojo1.Student"/> -->
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>

and i have getting erro like this
Sep 5, 2013 11:51:25 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.6.0_43\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/java/jdk1.6.0_43/bin/../jre/bin/server;C:/Program Files/java/jdk1.6.0_43/bin/../jre/bin;C:/Program Files/java/jdk1.6.0_43/bin/../jre/lib/amd64;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.6.0_43\bin;C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.8.4\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin;C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Smartbar\Application\;D:\eclipse;;.
Sep 5, 2013 11:51:25 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:crudhibernate' did not find a matching property.
Sep 5, 2013 11:51:25 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:crudannotation' did not find a matching property.
Sep 5, 2013 11:51:25 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Sep 5, 2013 11:51:25 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Sep 5, 2013 11:51:25 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1050 ms
Sep 5, 2013 11:51:25 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Sep 5, 2013 11:51:25 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.40
Sep 5, 2013 11:51:26 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(E:\projects\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\crudannotation\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Sep 5, 2013 11:51:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt is already defined
Sep 5, 2013 11:51:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core is already defined
Sep 5, 2013 11:51:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core is already defined
Sep 5, 2013 11:51:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt_rt is already defined
Sep 5, 2013 11:51:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt is already defined
Sep 5, 2013 11:51:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt is already defined
Sep 5, 2013 11:51:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions is already defined
Sep 5, 2013 11:51:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/permittedTaglibs is already defined
Sep 5, 2013 11:51:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/scriptfree is already defined
Sep 5, 2013 11:51:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql_rt is already defined
Sep 5, 2013 11:51:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql is already defined
Sep 5, 2013 11:51:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql is already defined
Sep 5, 2013 11:51:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml_rt is already defined
Sep 5, 2013 11:51:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml is already defined
Sep 5, 2013 11:51:27 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml is already defined
Sep 5, 2013 11:51:27 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(E:\projects\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\crudhibernate\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Sep 5, 2013 11:51:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt is already defined
Sep 5, 2013 11:51:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core is already defined
Sep 5, 2013 11:51:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core is already defined
Sep 5, 2013 11:51:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt_rt is already defined
Sep 5, 2013 11:51:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt is already defined
Sep 5, 2013 11:51:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt is already defined
Sep 5, 2013 11:51:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions is already defined
Sep 5, 2013 11:51:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/permittedTaglibs is already defined
Sep 5, 2013 11:51:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/scriptfree is already defined
Sep 5, 2013 11:51:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql_rt is already defined
Sep 5, 2013 11:51:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql is already defined
Sep 5, 2013 11:51:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql is already defined
Sep 5, 2013 11:51:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml_rt is already defined
Sep 5, 2013 11:51:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml is already defined
Sep 5, 2013 11:51:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml is already defined
Sep 5, 2013 11:51:28 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Sep 5, 2013 11:51:28 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Sep 5, 2013 11:51:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 2878 ms
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.cfg.Environment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Sep 5, 2013 11:51:38 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Studentdemoservlet] in context with path [/crudannotation] threw exception
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.pojo1.Student
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:548)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:1338)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:33)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:27)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:535)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:523)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:519)
    at com.pojo1.CreateStudent.intercourse(CreateStudent.java:20)
    at com.pojo1.Studentdemoservlet.doGet(Studentdemoservlet.java:38)
    at com.pojo1.Studentdemoservlet.doPost(Studentdemoservlet.java:48)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1008)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Answer (score 0):

this will not work at all because You have to list your classes in your session factory configuration.

In order to use annotations with hibernate and spring, you have to use `AnnotationSessionFactoryBean`

```
 <bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.pojo1</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    ....
 </bean>
```

or if you are not using spring then you can list your classes in your session factory configuration by declaring yoyr entity class in the **persistence.xml** file:

```
<persistence ...>
    <persistence-unit ...>

        <class>com.pojo1</class>
        <class>com.pojo2</class>

    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

hope this will solve your problem